# Convert Multidimensional array into differnet Multidimensional for output PHP, Excel

Tags: php, arrays

(i may have the terms incorrect ( maybe why i go no results in Google) so feel free to correct my terms).
I need to change an array that outputs

```
{"Source":["BKD060818","BKD060818",],"Qty":["15","23"],"ISBN":["9780805079333","9780143118978",],
"Title":["    ","    ",],"Author":["Boyle","Thurston Clarke"],"Price":["2.50","3.43"],
"Guide":["a","f",]}
```

to

```
{"Source":"BKD060818","Qty":15, "ISBN":"9781452128450", "Title":" ","Author":"Boyle","Price":"2.50","Guide":"a"},
{"Source":"BKD060818","Qty":23, "ISBN":"9780143118978", "Title":" ","Author":"Thurston Clarke","Price":"3.43","Guide":"f"}
```

the code

```
if(!empty($guides)){
    foreach($guides as $key=>$value) {

        $isbn10Array[$i] = $row['isbn10'];
        $isbn13Array[$i] = $row['isbn13'];

        if(!empty($value)) {
            $guideArray[$i] = $key;
            $qtyArray[$i] = $value;

            switch ($guideArray[$i]) { 
            }//leftout code here that is large switch statment

            $guideRefArray[$i] = $guideRef;   
            $poArray[$i] = $po;
            $i++;
         }
    }//FOREACH
}//NOT EMPTY GUIDES      
}//END OF WHILE LOOP //never started a while loop here?

$ships = array('Source'=>$poArray,
                           'Qty'=>$qtyArray,
                           'ISBN'=>$isbn13Array,
                           'Title'=>$titleArray,
                           'Author'=>$authorArray,
                           'Price'=>$PriceArray,
                           'Guide'=>$guideArray,

                          );
```

$ships outputs what i have now what i am looking is to move it into something like

```
$decision[$i] = array('Source'=>$po,
                           'Qty'=>$qty,
                           'ISBN'=>$isbn13,
                           'Title'=>$title,
                           'Author'=>$author,
                           'Price'=>$Price,
                           'Guide'=>$guide,

                          );
```

Comment: Your first step would be to produce valid json, the string you have is not.

Comment: echo json_encode($ships);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json posted in the question isn't valid, if this is a typo an you actually have valid json you can do the following:

```
$json = '{
    "Source": ["BKD060818", "BKD060818"],
    "Qty": ["15", "23"],
    "ISBN": ["9780805079333", "9780143118978"],
    "Title": ["    ", "    "],
    "Author": ["Boyle", "Thurston Clarke"],
    "Price": {
        "0": "2.50",
        "27": "3.43"
    },
    "Guide": ["a", "f"]
 }';    


$array = json_decode($json, true); 

foreach($array as $index=>$value){
    $i = 0;
    while($i <= count($array[$index])-1){
        if(($i == 1)&& ($index == "Price")){
            $new[$i][$index] = $array[$index][27]; //because one of the indexes of price is 27?
        }else{
            $new[$i][$index] = $array[$index][$i];      
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

var_dump($new); 
output is 
array(2) {
   [0]=>
     array(7) {
     ["Source"]=>
     string(9) "BKD060818"
     ["Qty"]=>
     string(2) "15"
     ["ISBN"]=>
     string(13) "9780805079333"
     ["Title"]=>
     string(4) "    "
     ["Author"]=>
     string(5) "Boyle"
     ["Price"]=>
     string(4) "2.50"
     ["Guide"]=>
     string(1) "a"
   }
   [1]=>
     array(7) {
     ["Source"]=>
     string(9) "BKD060818"
     ["Qty"]=>
     string(2) "23"
     ["ISBN"]=>
     string(13) "9780143118978"
     ["Title"]=>
     string(4) "    "
     ["Author"]=>
     string(15) "Thurston Clarke"
     ["Price"]=>
     string(4) "3.43"
     ["Guide"]=>
     string(1) "f"
   }
}
```

You can then encode the arrays back to json like so:

```
$array1 = json_encode($new[0]); 
$array2 = json_encode($new[1]);
```

Comment: i did have a typo, i tried what you put here ( taking out     $array = json_decode($json, true); because i encode the json later in the file. and i got a null respoce

Comment: foreach($ships as $index=>$value){
    $i = 0;
    while($i <= count($array[$index])-1){
        
            $new[$i][$index] = $array[$index][$i];      
        
        $i++;
    }

Comment: If you took out the `json_decode()` then it's not going to work...If `json_decode()` produces null, then it's because you've not passed it valid json. The example string you provided is not valid json

Comment: your code is correct ( i did not change one of the $array to the correct term)

Comment: 1 issue, this is what i used            foreach($ships as $index=>$value){
    $z = 0;
    while($z <= count($ships[$index])-1){
        
            $new[$z][$index] = $ships[$index][$z];      
        $z++;
    }   if i have the same value in a row for the first one (as in the above code) it ignores that "row"